# How to iterate through dataset and train the model

Tags: loops, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to build a model wherein I want to iterate through 1st 80000 values and train the model, then train on next 80000 point and so on. Is it possible to do it and also allowed?

```
length=80000
train_data=[]
train_tar=[]

for i in range (0, len(X_train), length):
    train_data[i]=X_train.iloc[i:i+length, :]
    train_tar[i]=Y_train.iloc[i:i+length, :]
    
   

    X_training, X_val, Y_training, Y_val = train_test_split(train_data[i], train_tar[i], test_size=0.40,   shuffle=False )
    
    scaler1= StandardScaler()
    X_training =scaler1.fit_transform(X_training[i])
    X_val[i]=scaler1.transform(X_val[i])
    X_test[i]=scaler1.transform(X_test[i])

    scaler2= StandardScaler()
    
    Y_training[i] =scaler2.fit_transform(Y_train[i])
    Y_val[i]=scaler2.transform(Y_val[i])
    Y_test[i]=scaler2.transform(Y_test[i])
    
    train_gen[i] = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(  X_training[i], Y_training[i],  sequence_length=160, sequence_stride=1, batch_size=256,sampling_rate=1,shuffle=False)
    
    val_gen[i] = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array( X_val[i], Y_val[i], sequence_length=160, sequence_stride=1, batch_size=256,sampling_rate=1,shuffle=False)
    
    batch =train_gen
    inputs, target=batch
    input= inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2]
    print(input)
    
    
    def ann():
    
    
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(1000, input_shape=input))
        model.add(Dense(100))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 1e-6), loss= 'mse', metrics=(['accuracy']))
        model.summary()
        return model

    model = ann()
    
    history=model.fit(train_gen[i], validation_data=val_gen[i], shuffle=True,epochs=10,verbose=1)
```

But I am getting error at the following line, how can I resolve this.

Indexerror:

```
train_data[i]=X_train.iloc[i:i+length, :]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Which error? Please update your post with the traceback.

Comment: @Corralien I have added the error I am getting

Answer (score 0):

`i` is not the right variable to index `train_data` and `train_tar`. Use enumerate to fix your problem:

```
# Now:
# i -> the index of the current loop
# j -> the slicing index
for i, j in enumerate(range(0, len(X_train), length)):
    train_data.append(X_train.iloc[j:j+length, :])
    train_tar.append(Y_train.iloc[j:j+length, :])

    # Rest of your code
```